# How To Fade Out Function With No Unique ID/Class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, while-loop

I don't normally post my server side code but I guess I can post abit to solve this issue,I have a staff page that loops through in a database as I am going to use the database to do other things like deleting/demoting the staff if they did anything wrong and to make the site neater. (don't like demoting staff but in a case I need to)

Anyway I am looping it through with a box what I want now is when one of the boxes are clicked I want it to go to a php page (via a ajax request to delete the user from the database) then hide or fade way by using the hide or fade function.

But the only issue is how can I do this when it's looping through? because the div does not have it's own class or id and I don't think jquery can connect to a database to get a unique id (since it's client side)

Here's some of my code to help

```
while($staff_info = mysqli_fetch_array($select_staff)) {
$account_name = $staff_info['account_name'];
$position = $staff_info['position'];
$description = $staff_info['description'];
echo "

<div id='staff_boxes'> <text style='float:right;'> <a href='#' class='delete_button'> X </a> </text>";
echo"
<h2>$account_name</h2>
$position
<p>$description</p>
</div> ";
}
```

Hoping to get some help and this I search Google but can't find nothing I might be doing it wrong for this type of system

Thanks!

Comment: If there is no unique id/class then what is the mechanism you have in place to search the element? E.g. child of an element with unique id? last row in table, etc..? If you can't specifically select an element from DOM tree then I don't think you can manipulate it.... In your case it seems you can navigate UP from clicked element in DOM tree and fade out the parent element that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can give each box a unique id like this with your code:

```
while($staff_info = mysqli_fetch_array($select_staff)) {
$id = $staff_info['id']; // assuming you have an id field in your DB
$account_name = $staff_info['account_name'];
$position = $staff_info['position'];
$description = $staff_info['description'];
echo "

<div id='staff_boxes_$id'> <text style='float:right;'> <a href='#' class='delete_button'> X </a> </text>";
echo"
<h2>$account_name</h2>
$position
<p>$description</p>
</div> ";
}
```

Alternatively, you can give all the divs the same class (e.g. `<div class="staff_box"> ... </div>` then use jQuery like this:

```
$('.staff_box').each(function(index) {
    var box = $(this);
    box.children('.delete_button').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        box.hide();
    })
});
```

Comment: Okay... if you need help, you'll have to give more details than "doesent work" [sic].

Comment: tried that but the code does nothing maybe I am doing something wrong
but thanks for your help so far

Comment: is there away to get jquery to retrieve the class name then i can use that?

Comment: Yes but I couldn't find much since I didn't know how to put it in words and you have headed me in to the right direction so I try googling again

Comment: Google `jquery get class of element` or something along those lines.

Comment: Will when I go into inpect element with chrome it's displaying them as seperate id names now so it shouldnt be that hard now
Thanks ;)